# obtener option seleccionada en datalist con vueJS

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy creando un componente de vueJS el cual contiene un dataList con option dinamicas, ya que se llena desde la base de datos. Necesito obtener el value de la opción seleccionada, pero no lo consigo. Adjunto el código de mi componente:

```
    <template>

    <div>
        <input list="usuarios" class="form-control mt-3">

        <datalist id="usuarios">

          <option v-for="data in usuarios" :val="data.id" @click="seleccionado($data.id)">{{data.nombre}}</option>

        </datalist>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                usuarios: [],
            };

        },
        created: function () {
            this.cargar();
        },
        methods: {
            cargar: function () {
                let url = "/getUsers";
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.usuarios = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            seleccionado: function(event){
                console.log(event.value);
            }
            
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que he resulto mi problema, aunque me gustaría que apareciera el nombre y no el id, pero bueno:

He usado v-on:input para llamar a la función y en la función obtengo el valor seleccionado

```
<template>

<div>
        <input list="usuarios" class="form-control mt-3" v-on:input="seleccionado">

        <datalist id="usuarios">

          <option v-for="data in usuarios" :value="data.id">{{data.nombre}}</option>

        </datalist>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                usuarios: [],
                source: '',
            };

        },
        created: function () {
            this.cargar();
        },
        methods: {
            cargar: function () {
                let url = "/getUsers";
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.usuarios = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            seleccionado: function(e){
                console.log("source = "+this.source+" new value = "+e.target.value);
            }
            
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

En Vue, puedes enviar información adicional junto con una opción de un datalist utilizando un objeto de JavaScript en lugar de una cadena de texto para el valor de cada opción. Por ejemplo:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" list="countries" v-model="selectedCountry">
    <datalist id="countries">
      <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.name" :key="country.code">
        {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCountry: '',
      countries: [
        { name: 'United States', code: 'US' },
        { name: 'Mexico', code: 'MX' },
        { name: 'Canada', code: 'CA' },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Ahora, en lugar de simplemente tener una cadena de texto para cada opción, tienes un objeto que contiene información adicional sobre el país, como su código. Esto se puede acceder en el componente de Vue y utilizar en función de tus necesidades.